# jquery how to get the value of (this) from multiple selector

Tags: jquery, this, attr

is it possible in jquery to get the value .attr() of (this) object?

an alert(this) returns `true[object HTMLInputElement]` so the `==` wont work

```
  $("#tag1, #tag2").keyup(function(event){
         if(this == "#tag1"){
            alert("This is tag1");
            };
         if(this == "#tag2"){
            alert("This is tag1");
                };
```

thx
Art

Comment: dude when you have to do different thing for tag1 and tag2 then why don't you use seperate block of codes for them

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not possible to get the selector that caused the current element to be matched - there are many possible selectors for a given element. While it would be theoretically possible if the jQuery object created by `$("#tag1, #tag2")` was still available, it would be incredibly ugly.

However, you can simply use `this.id` to access the element's ID (`'tag1'` or `'tag2'` in your case) and use it in your code:

```
$("#tag1, #tag2").keyup(function(event) {
    if(this.id == "tag1") {
        alert("This is tag1");
    }
    if(this.id == "tag2") {
        alert("This is tag1");
    }
});
```

If there is no common code at all for the two elements it's much better to use two selectors and functions instead of putting everything in a single function.

Comment: giving this correct cause you was quickest on the reply. And can also use this.name, thx to all for fast replies

Comment: Names are not necessarily unique so using the ID is usually better. Especially if you select the elements by ID anyway.

Answer (score 2):

You could compare the id using `this.id` (probably preferred), or use [jQuery's `is()`](http://api.jquery.com/is/) method;

```
  $("#tag1, #tag2").keyup(function (event) {
      if (this.id == "tag1") {
          alert("This is tag1");
      };
      if (this.id == "tag2") {
          alert("This is tag2");
      };
```

or...

```
  $("#tag1, #tag2").keyup(function (event) {
      if ($(this).is("#tag1")) {
          alert("This is tag1");
      };
      if ($(this).is("#tag2")) {
          alert("This is tag2");
      };
```

Answer (score 1):

You want this? :

```
$("#tag1, #tag2").keyup(function(event){
     alert("This is" + $(this).attr('id'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use switch too

```
$("#tag1, #tag2").keyup(function(event){
  target = $(this).attr('id');
     switch(target) {
     case:"#tag1"
        alert("This is tag1");
        break;
     case:"#tag2"
        alert("This is tag2");
        break;
      }
 });
```